# reduce compilation time of C program when there are 30 simultaneous programs

Tags: php, gcc, windows-xp, cygwin

I am trying to be make a online gcc compiler which can be accessed by the browser. For all this I have use php,cygwin on window XP. Actually I am giving the code window on the browser to the user.

---

**The general process is as:**

1. $source write in .c file
2. .c file compile by gcc compiler and .exe file created
3. the output of .exe file is shown to the user.

It's supposed that there is no read function in c program for testing I am use only a single `printf` statement.

---

**The problem is:**

If there are about to 30 simultaneous request means 30 users compiler the program at the same point of time then it will produce output in about 15 seconds, which is too long.

Can some please one help me to reduce this time. Each suggestions are welcomed

Can I just read the output of C program with out making a .exe file.

Comment: Let me know... Are you giving user the ability to execute compiled C code on your machine? If so, what have you done to sandbox all this environment? ...The compilation performance is your last problem.

Comment: @lorenzo-s ya the compiled code is executed on my machine. All things is going right but I have problem with time

Comment: Did you get what I mean with *sandbox environment*? What if I write `while(1) {}` and run it? What if I write `write_virus_to_file()` and run it? Etc, etc...

Comment: @lorenzo-s I have handle all the cases at my end by checking the C code by regex and many more options

Comment: _Checking C code with a regex_? Wow. If you don't sandbox that, you're in for trouble.

Answer (score 1):

A starting point could be exploring distributed build systems.

On Windows I have known a (non-free) solution is [Incredibuild](http://www.xoreax.com/). We used it for one of our projects around 8 years ago, and it reduced *clean and build* time from 25 minutes to around 5 minutes. There is a review of it [here](http://gamesfromwithin.com/how-incredible-is-incredibuild).

Right now, as I just searched for other alternatives and non-windows solutions I have also found [distcc](http://code.google.com/p/distcc/).

There is also a discussion (seemingly old) here about [alternatives to Incredibuild](http://discuss.fogcreek.com/joelonsoftware/default.asp?cmd=show&ixPost=120243).

Answer (score 0):

If the C source code are almost the same for each compilation request, you can use compiler cache enabled building system. E. g. waf and cmake. They can utilized the copy of the previous building to speed up the compilation.

Comment: Can u please tell me in details, I don't understand it. and the source code may be different depend upon user to user.